# How to make golang print all the fields in JSON?

Tags: json, go

I'm still learning Go (coming from Python) and I'm trying to automate a task in AWS. I have this requirement at work that I need to write the JSON output to a file but I'm struggling how to print all the fields in my struct. I'm missing the `Basket` field.

I want it to be printed like this:

```
{
  "Basket": [
    {
      "Name": "Apple",
      "Color": "Red"
    },
    {
      "Name": "Banana",
      "Color": "Yellow"
    }
  ]
}
```

But I'm only getting this:

```
[
  {
    "Name": "Apple",
    "Color": "Red"
  },
  {
    "Name": "Banana",
    "Color": "Yellow"
  }
]
```

You can find my code here in [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mMblVoOg_u8).

Comment: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce **it in the question itself**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the fruit in a basket.

The difference between the expected output and actual output is that the array is wrapped with an object in the expected output. Modify the corresponding Go types to match the structure of the expected output.

```
var data = struct{ Basket []Fruit }{Basket: fruits}
dat, err := json.MarshalIndent(&data, "", "  ")
```

https://play.golang.org/p/7g9HDZ38XxU

Alternatively, change the existing `Basket` type to match the JSON and use that:

```
type Basket struct {
    Basket []Fruit
}

...

dat, err := json.MarshalIndent(&Basket{Basket:fruit}, "", "  ")
```

Answer (score 1):

In your printJSON function you were just printing out the slide of fruits the basket. Creating and printing a basket struct and adding a JSON tag to the field Basket achieves what you want:

https://play.golang.org/p/aJcbP97CDGt

```
type Basket struct {
    Fruits []Fruit `json:"Basket"`
}

// Prints the output in JSON format.
func printJSON() {
    dat, err := json.MarshalIndent(Basket{fruits}, "", "  ")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("This is printJSON().")
    fmt.Println(string(dat))
}
```